# How to create a clickable irregularly-shaped region in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, shapes, android-vectordrawable

I want to show the clickable image under a transparent cloud image that could not rectangular space filled.
[image]

when use `ImageView` and click on object (blow image), clicked on cloud.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a RelativeLayout and stack the images in Z order by keeping the front most image as the last element of the RelativeLayout.

Then what you can do is take onClickListener of all the Images and do nothing in the Cloud image and keep the body of onClick empty.

While you can provide proper onClick to the image you want the operation to be performed with.

Hope this helps

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    //hidden Image
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    //Frontmost image
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your rectangle have a custom color, so we can take advantage of this state, for **ex :** and by using `onTouch()` we can click on color only.

```
   public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent ev) 
{

    final int action = ev.getAction();

    final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
    final int evY = (int) ev.getY();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
           break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
           ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById (YOUR_IMG_DRAWABLE);
           img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
           Bitmap imgbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache()); 
           img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
           int pxl = imgbmp.getPixel(evX, evY);
           int redComponent = Color.red(pxl);
           int greenComponent = Color.green(pxl);
           int blueComponent = Color.blue(pxl);

           //using color here 

          if(pxl == Color.MAGENTA){
          //do what you want
           } 

           break;
    }

}
```